# Why do equal duration transitions take different amounts of time?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have two nested elements: `A` and `B`. The outer element `A` is the same size as the inner element `B`. Element `B` contains some text. Both elements have a CSS transition with a duration of one second. On hover `A` changes the text colour, while `B` changes the background colour.

```css
#A {
  color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#B {
  font-size: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#A:hover {
  color: green;
}

#B:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div id="B">Example Text</div>
</div>
```

I expected the transitions would complete at the same time, however the background transition finishes before the text transition. What causes this behaviour?

Comment: They do take the same amount of time, but the way that "red" transitions into "green" is probably what gives a different visual impression here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by [this Chrome bug](https://crbug.com/1111817) (and [this Webkit one](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214352)).
Basically they do fire the transitions of inherited properties once per level, and each level will delay the next one by the transition's duration.

You could avoid this issue by ensuring that the inherited property (here `color`) gets transitioned only once:

```css
#A {
  color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#B {
  font-size: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: background-color 1s; /* limit this transition to bg-color only */
}

#A:hover {
  color: green;
}

#B:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div id="B">Example Text</div>
</div>
```

or

```css
#A {
  color: red;
}

#B {
  font-size: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s; /* set the transition only on the child */
}

#A:hover {
  color: green;
}

#B:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div id="B">Example Text</div>
</div>
```